# How do I clean an .on event listener when the component doesn't have removeEventListener?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, socket.io

I'm using socket.io inside a React browser front end. I'm using the socket to stream live updates from a console running on the server. I'm streaming using socket.io-stream.

I've got it to work, but when I try to clean up after myself, I end up with a `removeEventListener is not a function` error. Indeed, there is no such function.

So how do I clean the listener? I tried `socket.removeEventListener` but it doesn't do anything (no crash, but I still get old events fired).

---

I'm providing a fully functional example below (using a simple `setInterval` to stream

Client:

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";

const io = require("socket.io-client");
const ios = require("socket.io-stream");

const socket = io("http://localhost:4000");

export default class GeneratePackage extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { serverConsole: "" };

    this.serverStream = null;

    this.onChangeConsole = this.onChangeConsole.bind(this);
    this.startProcess = this.startProcess.bind(this);
    this.onStream = this.onStream.bind(this);
    this.onStreamRead = this.onStreamRead.bind(this);

    ios(socket).on("stream from server", this.onStream);
    console.log("Constructor");
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("Did mount");
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    console.log("Unmount");
    //It crashes here with TypeError: ios(...).removeEventListener is not a function
    ios(socket).removeEventListener("stream from server");
  }

  startProcess() {
    this.setState({ serverConsole: "" });
    socket.emit("begin");
  }

  onStream(stream, data) {
    console.log("Got a SERVER stream with " + data + " " + stream);

    this.serverStream = stream;
    stream.on("readable", this.onStreamRead);
  }

  onStreamRead() {
    var buf = this.serverStream.read();
    let text = buf.toString();

    console.log(text);
    let total = this.state.serverConsole + text + "\r";
    this.setState({ serverConsole: total });
  }

  onChangeConsole(event) {
    this.setState({ serverConsole: event.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <div>Test</div>
        <button onClick={this.startProcess}>Start Process</button>&nbsp;
        <textarea
          type="text"
          name="Server Console Log"
          className="form-control"
          placeholder=""
          value={this.state.serverConsole}
          onChange={this.onChangeConsole}
          style={{ height: 300 }}
        />
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Server:

```js
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const server = app.listen(4000);
const io = require("socket.io")(server);
const ios = require("socket.io-stream");

io.on("connection", socket => {
  console.log(new Date().toTimeString().substr(0, 8) + " a user connected");

  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    console.log(new Date().toTimeString().substr(0, 8) + "a user disconnected");
  });

  socket.on("begin", () => {
    stream = ios.createStream();
    stream.write("Starting to stream");
    ios(socket).emit("stream from server", stream, "Some name");
    setInterval(() => {
      stream.write("Poke!");
    }, 1000);
  });
});
```

Comment: Does socket.io-stream have removeEventListener function??

Comment: @elvis_ferns: of course it DOESN'T, why would you even ask that?! :D Seriously, I didn't even expect this, since it has an .on function. So how do I remove the event then?!

Comment: `I've got it to work, but when I try to clean up after myself, I end up with a removeEventListener is not a function error.`

Comment: @elvis_ferns I was making a joke on the fact that yes, you are right :). I updated the question :)